# ¿Cómo alterar la forma en que el operador IN trae los datos en SQL?

Tags: php, sql

**Descripción:**

Estoy ejecutando la siguiente consulta SQL con el operador `IN`:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId IN ($list)"
```

**El problema:**

Sucede que mi `$list` es una lista la cual contiene ids de usuarios de forma desordenada, pero por alguna razón el operador IN ordena los ids de los usuarios de la lista de forma ascendente (de menor a mayor). Mi lista:

```
$implodeBusinessIds = implode(', ', $ids);
```

**¿Qué necesito?**

Lo que quiero es que el operador `IN` no ordene los ids de la lista, sino que deje los ids en el orden que vienen.

**Ejemplo:**

La lista trae algo parecido a esto:

```
(9, 47, 5, 30, 1, 23, 10)
```

Como se puede observar en el ejemplo, mi lista trae los ids de forma desordenada y es en ese mismo orden que quiero que obtener los datos, en lugar de que IN lo haga de forma ascendente.

**Pregunta:**
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el operador `IN` deje de ordenar los ids de la lista para que empiece a buscar los datos en función del orden original que tenga mi lista?

Comment: Tener ordenada la fila afecta a tu resultado? Al final, el operador IN si encuentra tan solo 1 valor entre los elementos de la lista que le pases (sea cual sea) ejecutará toda la query.

Comment: El orden del IN no impacta para nada en el resultado de la consulta... asi que no tiene sentido tu pregunta hasta ahora.. cual es tu problema real?

Comment: @gbianchi en el ejemplo que di de la lista (9, 47, 5, 30, 1, 23, 10) al ejecutar la consulta con IN, obtengo primero los resultados de 1, luego de 5, luego de 9, 10, 23, 30, 47 por lo que el operador IN me los está ordenando

Comment: @lsanchezo Cuando se ejecuta la query, los datos que se traen vienen ordenados por el userId de forma ascendente. Yo quiero que los datos no vengan ordenados por userId de forma ascendente, sino que vengan con el mismo orden en el que estaban los ids en la lista

Comment: Cuando ejecutas una consulta, en cualquier base de datos, los datos no vienen ordenados de una forma predefinida a menos que incluyas una clausula Order by. Lo que ves, es como los encuentra la base de datos de forma mas rapida... asi que no, no tiene nada que ver.. y los ves ordenados por userId, porque de casualidad la base de datos los encuentra mas rapido asi.. si le cambias el userID al primer registro y le pones un numero cualquiera, lo va a seguir trayendo primero, porque la base de datos no ordena.. trae cosas...

Comment: si los queres ordenar, usa order by

Comment: ok, entiendo @gbianchi muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Prueba con `ORDER BY find_in_set(userId, '9,47,5,30,1,23,10')`.